# Как настроить логгирование log4j в разные файлы?

Tags: java, scala, log4j, log4j2, spark

Мне бы хотелось настроить логгирование моей программы, написанной на ***scala*** с использованием ***spark***, я понимаю, как настроить логгирование в один файл, с записью в конец (***RollingAppender***), но хотелось бы, чтобы при каждом запуске программы создавался новый файл с уникальным названием, например, ***example-[*дата или timestamp*].log***.
Сейчас запись ведется в два файла: Абсолютно всего логи идут в файл spark.log, а логи, которые я пишу самостоятельно, идут в файл sparkU.log

Сейчас мой файл log4j.properties выглядит следующим образом:

```
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=/var/log/spark.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n

log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.File=/var/log/sparkU.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.filePattern=spark[%i].log
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c - %m%n


log4j.rootLogger=INFO, RollingAppender, myConsoleAppender

log4j.logger.myLogger=WARN, RollingAppenderU

# The noisier spark logs go to file only
log4j.logger.spark.storage=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.storage=false
log4j.logger.spark.scheduler=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.scheduler=false
log4j.logger.spark.CacheTracker=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.CacheTracker=false
log4j.logger.spark.CacheTrackerActor=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.CacheTrackerActor=false
log4j.logger.spark.MapOutputTrackerActor=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.MapOutputTrackerActor=false
log4j.logger.spark.MapOutputTracker=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivty.spark.MapOutputTracker=false
```

Comment: используй logback.xml [Как логировать в разные файлы](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2489569/5122436)

Comment: а вообще это стандартный функционал logback -- указание даты-времени при логировании. Попробуй как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36707798/5122436) (указание времени) и как [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53330425/5122436) (новый файл на каждый старт)